# Easing With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to get the easing function to work with my parallax. Trying to make the board move a little cleaner. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry I'm new here and whenever I try to post my code it tells me I cannot have an image. I put it up on my host.

http://cheapramen.com/JQuery/skate/moveit.html

Answer (score 1):

Animations in jquery are performed asynchronously, therefore,  they can take advantage of other functions that manipulate the animation timeline, i.e easing functions.

Having said that, AFAIK this version of the parallax plugin does not leverage jquery animations (e.g. `.animate()`, `.fadeTo()` et. al), Instead it rolls it's own animation functions. That's why you cannot use the easing plugin like you have in your code.

You can play around with the values for `$.fn.jparallax.settings.frameDuration` (defaults to 25) and see if that makes the animation any smoother...

Comment: If I put the duration past 35 it starts to look choppy and weird. I will continue to tinker with the other settings.